# How to return a tuple in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tuples

```
type Record=([Char],[Char],[Char],[Char],[Char])

createAccount::IO()->Record
createAccount=do
    putStrLn "Enter First Name"
    fname<-getLine
    putStrLn "Enter Last Name"
    lname<-getLine
    putStrLn "Enter State"
    state<-getLine
    putStrLn "Enter City"
    city<-getLine
    putStrLn "Enter House No."
    hnum<-getLine
    let hnumInt = read hnum :: Integer
    putStrLn "Enter Contact"
    contact<-getLine
    return (fname,lname,state,city,contact)
```

Comment: getting this errorType error in explicitly typed binding
*** Term           : createAccount
*** Type           : IO ([Char],[Char],[Char],[Char],[Char])
*** Does not match : IO () -> Record

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any reason to get the house number; `createAccount` doesn't use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is saying that the type signature for `createAccount` is actually:

```
createAccount :: IO ([Char],[Char],[Char],[Char],[Char])
```

not `IO() -> Record` as you declared it to be.

Options to fix it:

- Change the type signature to `IO ([Char],[Char],[Char],[Char],[Char])` (or equivalenly: `IO Record`)
- Remove the type signature - you don't need it as Haskell can figure it out.

Comment: *Remove the type signature - you don't need it as Haskell can figure it out.* Adding type signatures to all top-level bindings is good practice, though.